# what .js file required for supporting replace_html in controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am having page.replace_html with a partial in the controller. What is the correnponding .js file that i had to include to support this .

Thanks,
Ramya.

Comment: .js file as in the partial or the action's js template ? Whatever it is, there is not hard and fast rule on the name of any file and it depends on what you want to render. afaik, the partial would be an erb file, just instead of a page refresh the element id mentioned there, it contents would get replaced with the partial's content.
Your question misses a lot of information.

Comment: no no i am asking about the mandatory files like jquery.js ,prototype.js

Comment: use jquery and its $.ajax functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Rails 2.3.x Prototype and its dependencies are already present in the framework. In you application you can include prototype.js specifically or use 
`<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>` which includes all the js files Rails provides, if application.js is there then that is included as well. PrototypeHelper in rails gives you the methods `replace_html` etc. If you use jquery instead of prototype then you would have to use [jrails](https://github.com/aaronchi/jrails) plugin.

In Rails 3 jQuery is present by default and jrails is not going to work. Rails 3 removed the the link between its Javascript helpers and Prototype, as unobtrusive way is recommended to do those things. However, you could user the [Prototype Legacy Helper](https://github.com/rails/prototype_legacy_helper) provided by Rails to get those methods.

Comment: Hi I am getting the following error on trying to install the prototype helper  /home/ramya/tcm/tcm/config/environment.rb:7: undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (NameError)from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in